# Proxmox cron.daily log error

Tags: cron, proxmox

I am having a problem with cron.daily job in Proxmox. 
Its giving me this error:

```
/etc/cron.daily/pve:
Can't stat /var/log/pve/tasks/6: No such file or directory
at /etc/cron.daily/pve line 78
```

The `/var/log/pve/tasks/6` folder is missing, but I can create it. I only want to know if I create it would it break something? Seems like the cronjob can not create it, but only wants to write in to it.

So my main question is that is it safe to create that log folder?

Comment: Assume yes. Creating a log folder should always be safe. If a program harms your OS because you created its log folders, then it's really poorly written (or it's a virus you helped working ;) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. It was not in the log folder, but in the cronjob task. Fixed!

Fixed it by adding the log folder and giving it 770 premissions so root:root can access it in proxmox.

It does not write anything to it, but proxmox VM needs it, even if the VM is not running.

Proxmox deleted the log folder in rotation.

Comment: And how did you fix it?  [Just in case anyone else ever runs into the same problem](http://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Here is a quick fix :

```
mkdir /var/log/pve/tasks/{{0..9},{A..F}} ; chmod /var/log/pve/tasks/{{0..9},{A..F}}
```

This will create the subdirectories in the /var/log/pve/tasks directory and set the correct permissions.